# Insertion in 3D arraylist

Tags: java, arraylist, 3d

I have created 3D ArrayList. I know initialization is done using this code

```
ArrayList<ArrayList<ArrayList>> ll=new ArrayList<ArrayList<ArrayList>>();  
for(int j=0;j<n;j++){
    ll.add(new ArrayList(new ArrayList()));
}
```

But I dont know how insert values in it.
I am familiar with 2D arraylist in which inserting value b at a index is done using

`ll.get(a).add(b);`

but I dont know how to insert value into 3D arrayList.

I am solving question http://www.spoj.com/problems/BENEFACT/
in which I think longest distance in tree is the answer. I used 3D ArrayList
here, 2dimension to store connection of places and 3rd dimension to store distance

Is this correct approach? Is Any other approach possible in which solution is obtained easier than using 3d ArrayList?

Comment: `new ArrayList(new ArrayList())` means: Create a new list (2nd one), then create another list (1st one) and populate it with the content of the first list, which is empty, so you just get a single empty list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think if you want to access an object at index i,j,k you can do it by

```
ll.get(i).get(j).get(k)
```

Or

```
ll.get(i).get(j).add(k,newObject)
```

Comment: You meant `get(i)` in the first one.

Comment: thanks this is answer i was searching for... But Is this true for n Dimension i.e. for 4th dimension ll.get(i).get(j).get(k).get(l) will work?

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your need, you probably don't want that. I didn't read the full description of the problem to solve (the link), but you just need 6 points in 3D space.

I'd suggest creating a `Point3D` class with `x`, `y`, and `z`, and then just a simple `List<Point3D>`.

Comment: I thought of this logic too,But problem with this is suppose I want all connection associated with X place then I have to traverse hole list.